# Get a specific cell value from PHP associative array

Tags: php

I have this array named '$books' coming out from database table :

```
Array(
   [0] => Book Object
        (
            [id] => ADW-STD-P5
            [stage] => P5
            [price] => 39
            [active] => 1
        )

    [1] => Book Object
        (
            [id] => ADW-STD-P4
            [stage] => P4
            [price] => 0
            [active] => 1
        )
        
        ...
```

I want to get a specific cell value of row '0' and column 'id'.
I have tried the following with no luck:

```
echo $books[0]['id'];
echo $books[0][0];
```

All above result this error Msg:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Book as array.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you load this data - as you have `[0] => Book Object`, I would assume that these are objects of a specific type.  If `Book` is a class, it may have access methods to fetch the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As u can see Book is an Object.

```
echo $books[0]->id
```